# Create a checkbox ist control by extending html helper in mvc 3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dynamic, controls, html-helper

I am trying to create a dynamic checkboxlist control with an extended html helper? The radio button list will be filled by a list of items? Not sure how to make this more flexible for any list items.

```
public static string CheckBoxList(this HtmlHelper helper, string name, <Some List> items)
        {
            var output = new StringBuilder();
            output.Append(@"<div class=""checkboxList"">");

            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                output.Append(@"<input type=""checkbox"" name=""");
                output.Append(name);
                output.Append("\" value=\"");
                output.Append(item.Value);
                output.Append("\"");

                output.Append(" />");
                output.Append(item.Value);
                output.Append("<br />");
            }

            output.Append("</div>");

            return output.ToString();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about passing in the value property name as a parameter and then getting that property with reflection?

```
var itemValue = item.GetType( ).GetProperty( propName ).GetValue( item, null );
```

So your method Signature is like so:

```
public static string CheckBoxList(this HtmlHelper helper, string name, List<object> items, string propName)
```